# Points are not being added to the score when correct answer is selected

Tags: java, swing, variables, jbutton, actionlistener

I am making a trivia game. When the user clicks on genre button on screen to answer a question, another window pop's up with the question and 4 jbuttons as possible answers. I tried to program it where when the correct option is clicked, points will be added to the user's score and if a incorrect option is clicked, they will loose a life, but it is not working.

I've made a button handler where when they click on a genre, it will open up a question with 4 options. Under that I put a if else if statement. If the correct answer is clicked, give the user points, else if, if it is incorrect, take away a life.

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getSource () == btnT1)
            {
                frame2.setVisible (true);
                btnT1.setEnabled (false);
                qTitle.setText ("Solar energy generates electricity from what source?");
                a1.setText ("The water");
                a2.setText ("The sun");
                a3.setText ("Fossil fuels");
                a4.setText ("The wind");

                if (e.getSource () == a2)
                {
                    score = score + 100;
                    frame2.setVisible (false);
                }
                else if (e.getSource () != a2)
                {
                    lives = lives - 1;
                    frame2.setVisible (false);
                }

            }
```

I want to add to the score and take away lives, but it is not working. Could you help me get it working? All help is appreciated, thank you.

Also, this code may also be useful to help solve the problem. These are all the panels, buttons, actionlisteners and so on.

```
private static void guiApp ()
    {

        ButtonHandler onClick = new ButtonHandler (); // calls on ButtonHandler class

        // Creating JPanels
        JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel ();
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel ();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel ();

        gameBoard.setLayout (new GridLayout (4, 5, 4, 4));
        titlePanel.setLayout (new BoxLayout (titlePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.setLayout (new BoxLayout (bottomPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Trivia Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // To monitor button clicks
        btnT1.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnT2.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnT3.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnS1.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnS2.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnS3.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnF1.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnF2.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnF3.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnM1.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnM2.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnM3.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnG1.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnG2.addActionListener (onClick);
        btnG3.addActionListener (onClick); 

        // Formatting widgets
        Font titleFont = new Font ("Forte", Font.BOLD, 36);

        title.setFont (titleFont);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment (title.CENTER);
        tech.setHorizontalAlignment (tech.CENTER);
        sports.setHorizontalAlignment (sports.CENTER);
        food.setHorizontalAlignment (food.CENTER);
        movies.setHorizontalAlignment (movies.CENTER);
        geo.setHorizontalAlignment (geo.CENTER);

        titlePanel.add (title);

        // Adds buttons to panel
        gameBoard.add (tech);
        gameBoard.add (sports);
        gameBoard.add (food);
        gameBoard.add (movies);
        gameBoard.add (geo);
        gameBoard.add (btnT1);
        gameBoard.add (btnS1);
        gameBoard.add (btnF1);
        gameBoard.add (btnM1);
        gameBoard.add (btnG1);
        gameBoard.add (btnT2);
        gameBoard.add (btnS2);
        gameBoard.add (btnF2);
        gameBoard.add (btnM2);
        gameBoard.add (btnG2);
        gameBoard.add (btnT3);
        gameBoard.add (btnS3);
        gameBoard.add (btnF3);
        gameBoard.add (btnM3);
        gameBoard.add (btnG3);
        bottomPanel.add (scoreText);
        bottomPanel.add (livesText);

        //Get the frame's content pane
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane ();

        // add panel to frame
        contentPane.add (gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add (titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add (bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //size the window.
        frame.setSize (550, 500);
        frame.setVisible (true);

        // Questions window
        JPanel qPanel = new JPanel ();

        qPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(qPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame ("Question");
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        a1.addActionListener (onClick);
        a2.addActionListener (onClick);
        a3.addActionListener (onClick);
        a4.addActionListener (onClick);

        qPanel.add (qTitle);
        qPanel.add (a1);
        qPanel.add (a2);
        qPanel.add (a3);
        qPanel.add (a4);        

        Container contentPane2 = frame2.getContentPane ();

        contentPane2.add (qPanel);

        //size the window.
        frame2.setSize (500, 200);
        frame2.setVisible (false);

        //Results Window
        JPanel resultsPanel = new JPanel ();
        JPanel rBottomPanel = new JPanel ();

        resultsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        rBottomPanel.setLayout (new BoxLayout (rBottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame ("Results");
        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        resultsPanel.add (resultsMessage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rBottomPanel.add (reset, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        rBottomPanel.add (exit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Container contentPane3 = frame3.getContentPane ();

        contentPane3.add (resultsPanel);
        contentPane3.add (rBottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //size the window.
        frame3.setSize (400, 300);
        frame3.setVisible (false);
    }
```

Comment: 1. Much repetitive code can be reduced by smart use of arrays, collections and loops. 2. Doing this can make your code much easier to debug. 3. If you need our help figuring out why code isn't working, best to create and post a valid [mre] / [mcve] program in your question. Else we really can't test this code.

Comment: When your listener is activated, the source is `btnT1`. It is not going to magically change to a1, a2, or a3 before the user has had time to interact with a new question, and so the button listener doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: It's like you're asking if the user has made the right choice *before* the user has had the opportunity to even make a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is wrong:

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource () == btnT1)
        {
            frame2.setVisible (true);
            btnT1.setEnabled (false);
            qTitle.setText ("Solar energy generates electricity from what source?");
            a1.setText ("The water");
            a2.setText ("The sun");
            a3.setText ("Fossil fuels");
            a4.setText ("The wind");

            if (e.getSource () == a2)
            {
                score = score + 100;
                frame2.setVisible (false);
            }
            else if (e.getSource () != a2)
            {
                lives = lives - 1;
                frame2.setVisible (false);
            }

        }
```

This handler will be activated when btnT1 is pressed, ***before*** any of the a1, a2, a3, or a4 buttons have been pressed, and so you're doing your logical testing *before* the user has had an opportunity to make a choice.

For this to work, the listeners on a1, a2, a3, and a4 would need to have the logic that this listener has.

If this were my program, I'd separate my GUI (the "view") from the logical portion of my program (the "model"), I'd create a non-GUI Question class, one that holds the text of questions, that holds the correct answer, that can check for correctness, and a GUI QuestionView, that displays the question and can check user response against the model (Question) that it holds -- I'd compartmentalize the whole thing, and not try to hard-code it as you're doing.

As an aside, please read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

---

For example, I would create a separate class for Question, a non-GUI class that holds a question String, an answer String and a possibleAnswers `ArrayList<String>` that holds all the answers that the user can select, something like this could work:

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private List<String> possibleAnswers;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String question, List<String> possibleAnswers, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;

        // randomize things:
        this.possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>(possibleAnswers);
        Collections.shuffle(this.possibleAnswers);
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public List<String> getPossibleAnswers() {
        return possibleAnswers;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    // test if String matches answer
    public boolean test(String possibleAnswer) {
        return answer.equals(possibleAnswer);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Q: ");
        sb.append(question);
        sb.append("; ");
        sb.append("A: ");
        sb.append(answer);
        sb.append("; ");
        sb.append(possibleAnswers);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I would separate the data from the code, and create a simple text file to hold questions. Again keep it simple. In a file created for an example program that I made, question data were held in several lines with a blank line separating questions.  The first line of each question contained the question text, the next line was the correct answer, and the next few lines were wrong answers. Again, a blank line separated questions. Note that in my Question class constructor above, I randomized the answers, so in the actual Question object, the first possible answer is no longer guaranteed to be the correct one. The text file could look like so:

QuestionsFile.txt

```
Who is buried in Grant's tomb?
Ulysses Grant
George Washington
Abraham Lincoln
Donald Trump

What color was Washington's white horse?
White
Blue
Green
Brown

How many days are there in a week?
7
4
2
3

What is 2 + 2?
4
2
11
I have no idea?

What is the largest celestial body in the solar system?
The sun
Jupiter 
Mars
What is the solar system?
```

I'd create code to read in this file line-by-line, creating Question objects as it reads, and placing them into an `ArrayList<Question>`.

I'd then create a JPanel that displays a single Question as a GUI, something with a JLabel to display the question String, a collection of JRadioButtons held in a nested JPanel that uses GridLayout to hold the possible answer Strings, and a JButton to submit the user's selection for grading.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QuestionViewPanel extends JPanel {
    private Question question; // model for this view
    private JLabel questionLabel;
    private ButtonGroup answersGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    private JButton clearAnswerButton = new JButton("Clear Answer");

    public QuestionViewPanel(Question question) {
        this.question = question;

        questionLabel = new JLabel(question.getQuestion());
        questionLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Question:"));

        JPanel possAnswersPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        possAnswersPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Possible Answers:"));
        for (String possAnswer : question.getPossibleAnswers()) {
            JRadioButton rBtn = new JRadioButton(possAnswer);
            rBtn.setActionCommand(possAnswer);
            answersGroup.add(rBtn);
            possAnswersPanel.add(rBtn);
        }

        clearAnswerButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        clearAnswerButton.addActionListener(e -> answersGroup.clearSelection());
        submitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(submitButton);
        bottomPanel.add(clearAnswerButton);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        add(questionLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(possAnswersPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void addSubmitListener(ActionListener listener) {
        submitButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public boolean testAnswer() {
        boolean result = false;
        ButtonModel model = answersGroup.getSelection();
        if (model != null) {
            String possibleAnswer = model.getActionCommand();
            result = question.test(possibleAnswer);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then create a quick and dirty driver class, one that creates the GUI, one that uses a CardLayout to swap QuestionViewPanel's, and that puts things together:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QuestionTest extends JPanel {
    // This String likely needs to be changed
    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "QuestionsFile.txt";
    private List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<QuestionViewPanel> questionViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel questionViewShowPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public QuestionTest(List<Question> questionsList) {
        this.questionsList = questionsList;
        for (Question question : questionsList) {
            QuestionViewPanel qView = new QuestionViewPanel(question);
            qView.addSubmitListener(new SubmitListener(qView));
            questionViewShowPanel.add(qView, question.getQuestion());
        }
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(questionViewShowPanel);
    }

    private class SubmitListener implements ActionListener {
        private QuestionViewPanel qView;

        public SubmitListener(QuestionViewPanel qView) {
            this.qView = qView;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean result = qView.testAnswer();
            String text = result ? "Correct!" : "Wrong!  The correct answer is: " 
                        + qView.getQuestion().getAnswer();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(qView, text, "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            cardLayout.next(questionViewShowPanel);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(List<Question> questionsList) {
        QuestionTest mainPanel = new QuestionTest(questionsList);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();

        InputStream questionsStream = QuestionTest.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_PATH);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(questionsStream);
        String question = "";
        String answer = "";
        List<String> possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();           
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                if (!question.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    questionsList.add(new Question(question, possibleAnswers, answer));
                    question = "";
                    answer = "";
                    possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            } else if (question.trim().isEmpty()) {
                question = line;
            } else {
                possibleAnswers.add(line);
                if (answer.trim().isBlank()) {
                    answer = line;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!question.trim().isEmpty()) {
            questionsList.add(new Question(question, possibleAnswers, answer));
            question = "";
            answer = "";
            possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(questionsList));
    }
}
```

The GUi from this code would look like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, that makes sense why it is not working. Do you have any possible solutions or suggestions?

Comment: @BlueElectro: see edit. The listeners need to be on the a1, a2, a3... buttons. And also you need to stop hard-coding this stuff -- separate the questions from the GUI. This will make your code much more flexible.