# Can you make a JPanel randomly generate each time a button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing

Basically just started coding in Java using Eclipse and as my first "serious" project I'm trying to code a simple quiz game. I already set up all the graphics and the answering system but I'm getting stuck at the part where, if you click the right answer, the JPanel restarts with a new question.

I already tried some solutions I've seen online including a do/while method, which proved worthless and calling the main method ( the one where all the code is) which seems impossible.

Here's the method I'm talking about:

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
```

{
//here was unnecessary stuff i cut out

```
     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon (Imagetesting.class.getResource(i+".jpg"));
     JLabel label = new JLabel (image);
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Quiz");
      JLabel x1 = new JLabel(question);
      
      JButton x2 = new JButton(answer1);
         //+ other graphic stuff
        
         f.getContentPane().add(MyPanel, "Center"); // Paste MyPanel in center
                                // of the contentPane    
         f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
         f.setVisible(true);
         x3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                
                 if(answer2.equals("therightanswer")){
                 score = score +1;
                 x1.setText("Right answer Punteggio:"+String.valueOf(punteggio)
                 // what am I supposed to put here?
                 );
              ;
                    }
             }});
```

So what am I supposed to do? Is it even possible to call the main method to make it restart? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to restart from scratch, consider that you can have more than one method in your application. You could have a frame-creating method called both from *main()* and from *actionPerformed()*. But consider also whether you intead just want the text to update in the existing panel.

Comment: You're starting with the wrong piece of the puzzle. First work on creating clean non-GUI OOPs-compliant code to handle the logical parts of the problem -- i.e., a class for each Question, one that has a String for the question, Strings for possible answers and the correct answer, code to be able to identify a correct response, and then try to hook this up to a GUI. When you create your GUI, don't put all into a single huge main method, but subdivide your GUI into smaller parts to divide and conquer the problem.

Comment: For example please check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554048/522444) to a similar recent question. In this answer, I swapped question-displaying JPanels using a CardLayout.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the labels into the actionPerformed function to change the values of those objects when the answer is correct.

Comment: But why can't you simply call the main() method?